# css priority when nesting: outer class higher than inner?

Tags: html, css

I am no expert in CSS, so the following confuses me. My basic understanding of CSS priority is that the more specific a declaration is, the higher is it's priority.

With that I thought that both links should have the same color, as in both cases the inner most element has the class `.inner`. But in my tests with both firefox and chrome(based), on the first link the rule for `a` descended of `.container` is applied.

```css
.container a{
  color: green;
}
.inner {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a href="google.com" class="inner">first</a>
    <a href="google.com" ><span class="inner">second</span></a>
</div>
```

I can solve my issue with the workaround I used for the second link, but I would be happier if I could understand what is going on ;)

Comment: Is your question, why isn't `<a href="google.com" class="inner">first</a>` colored red?

Comment: @j08691 yes, that is my question. It is answered, but I have to say the answer doesn't make me like CSS any more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS styles will be applied from top to bottom
So first,
Green color will be applied to  tag

When it comes to .inner: red
There are 2 elements that get affected with it
 - first 
 - span inside second

First element style will not be over written with red as it has high priority. Consider below values as examples for checking priority
Tag - 1 
class - 2
id - 3 (highest priority)

id --> class --> element(tag) for left to right is goes highest priority

So in your case
.inner = 2
.container a = 2+1 = 3

As there is another element(span) with class '.inner', its color will be changed to red

Answer (score 1):

`.container a` consists of a class selector and a type selector so it is more specific than `.inner` which is just a class selector. So the `<a>` elements are green.

Selectors only match the elements they select though, and `.container a` does not match `<span class="inner">second</span>` but `.inner` does.

Specificity is irrelevant here since there is only one selector that matches, so the span is red.

---

If the `.inner` rule did not exist, then the browser default stylesheet would cause the span to have `color: inherit` and it would pick up the green value from the parent `<a>` element which *is* matched by 
`.container a`.

Comment: But `color` is an inherited property, so the span is affected by that rule

Comment: @j08691 — That just means the *default* value is `inherit`. `.inner { color: red; }` changed the value from `inherit` to `red`.

Comment: Right, but I think the part of your answer above the line might confuse someone new to CSS.

Comment: yes, i think i understand that. But I don't understand why `.container a` gets higher priority than `.inner` in the first link

Comment: @cypherabe — You said it in the first line of your question. `.container a` (a class selector + a type selector) is more specific that `.inner` (just a class selector).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can understand in this way :-

First rule will apply to both the links so both `<a>` tag has font color green, but then you have `.inner` rule with red color, so it will override first rule to the inner span of `<a>` tag.

And for first `<a>` tag .inner will not apply because of parent class used in the `<a>` tag rule, So It will not affect by the second rule.